# Canny transform VS threshed image for HoughCircle

Tags: python, hough-transform, canny-operator, opencv

I'm try to build a robust coin detection on images using [HoughCircle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) with these params :

```py
blured_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(region_of_interest, (23, 23), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
rows = blured_roi.shape[0]
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blured_roi, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 0.9, rows/8,
param1=30, param2=50, minRadius=30, maxRadius=90)
```

The region of interest could be (300x300) or (1080x1920). So the `minRadius` and `maxRadius` aren't really helping here. But they are approximately the size of my coin in each type of image shape.

So to achieve that I tried many things. First of all, using simple GRAY image with a `GaussianBlur` filter.
It works on most of cases but if my coin border are similar tint as the background, the GRAY scale image will not really help to detect the right radius of my circle take a look at this example :

[image: image 1][image: image 2][image: image 3]

In second time, I tried to use edges of the coin to detect circles with [Canny Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de), but as you can see above the Canny filter not works as I hoped. So I applied a `GaussianBlur` of (13, 13).

*I also know that there is another canny transform call inside the `HoughCircle` method, but I wanted to be sure I'll get edges of the coin, because I'm losing them while blurring with `GaussianBlur`.*

Finally I tried using a threshed image, but I can't understand why it didn't works as well as excepted, because on this image we can hope there will never have any noises because it's only black&white (?), and the circle is almost perfect. And applied a `GaussianBlur` of (9, 9).

[image: threshed][image: canny edges][image: result houghcircle with canny edges]

Here you can see it failed to detect the coin on the threshed image, but it works with the canny edges image. But in many other cases Hough Transform on edges detection give an unperfected result, and I feel confiant about threshed image which as you can see reveal a nice circle.

**I would like to understand why it didn't works on the threshed image (like the example above), and what I could do to make it works.**

**EDIT 1:** So I discovered the different type of [BORDER](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5) to specify in the `GaussianBlur` method. I thought it would be really useful to improve the hough circle detection on the Threshed image, but it didn't goes as well as excepted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " it failed to detect the coin on the threshed image but not on the edges". Seems you are able to detect coin in your second example?

Comment: Yes the coin is detected by using the canny edges images and not the threshed image, that why I don't understand because it look easier to detect on the threshed image, instead of canny transform.

Comment: I notice that your object is black in that binary image ----> Hough circles algorithm will consider white pixels instead ....